# package.json for global dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

When writing node.js apps, almost always you have to deal not only with local dependencies but also global packages required for the app. What is the best and common way to deal with that? I've seen it's possible to run `npm` in preinstall phase

```
"scripts": {
   "preinstall": "npm i -g grunt-cli"
}
```

It is strange though to run npm install from within npm script itself, but I guess that works.

However, is not very convenient if it's required to install several packages. Is it possible to tell `npm` to take all listed packages from another file i.e. `package.global.json` and install all of them globally?

And again, is there some sort of convention?

Comment: Can you give an example of all of these global packages? Personally I'd treat any global package as a problem. For example, for Grunt, are you often running a ton of builds? Why not make an NPM script that calls a non-global grunt instead?

Comment: So you're saying - it should be encouraged to not to install packages globally, unless you really need them there. Like I dunno yeoman?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I consider *requiring* global modules for your build process to be a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). They work fine, but they fight against `npm` because they can't be added directly as dependencies. Instead, to use a package that includes a `bin` script to execute, I would recommend using the `scripts` field in `package.json` to provide a set of commands.

For example:

```
"dependencies": {
    "grunt-cli": "..."
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "grunt server",
    "test": "grunt test"
}
```

When you run `npm start`, `npm` will automatically add the location of the `grunt-cli` module into the `PATH`, and execute the `grunt` command to start the server, and running `npm test` will call through to the `grunt` test runner. This also means you have a really nice place for people to look to immediately know which commands are available to them, and it helps with consistency across the community. Note, `start` and `test` are special names in `npm`, so for other arbitrary commands, you need to run `npm run-script <scriptname>`

Generally I'd follow the pattern that if it is critical for the building and running of your module, do not require global modules, but use them to support enhanced workflows if needed.
The main thing here is that I would list the absolutely critical scripts. There is nothing wrong with *optionally* using global modules. For instance, you may have a ton of grunt commands and you can't list every permutation in the `package.json` and that is fine. For your machine, you can globally install `grunt-cli` so you can run all of the commands exposed by the `Gruntfile`.

Comment: But how about `mocha`. If I requires `mocha` to run test and the `mocha` need to be installed globally, how could I specify this kind of dependency?

Comment: Mocha does not need to be installed globally. You'd install it locally and use it in the `"test"` script just like the grunt example, then you'd run `npm test` to run your tests, rather than calling `mocha` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Forcible global install is not really a good idea. You can just install these packages locally. Global scripts will be available in `node_modules/.bin` folder, and also in `npm` scripts this folder will be added to path, so one can just `npm run grunt`

Comment: seriously, packages that require CLI, like grunt-cli, mocha etc. coffee-script locally?

Comment: yep, feels good. No conflicts, no confusion, no hard feelings